# Change the name of the Request Element in XSD file of a Spring Web Service

Tags: web-services, spring, xsd, wsdl

I have a Web Service with a method called TestMethod.

On the XSD file I have this:

```
<element name="TestMethodResponse">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="codRta" type="int" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>  
<element name="TestMethodRequest">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

As you can see, there is a TestMethodRequest and TestMethodResponse

This work OK!

Now, I need to make some changes.

This Web Service will be used to replace another Web Service.

So I need to call the methods on my Web Service equal to the older one.

That because my client have a Desktop Application (using the older Web Service) working, and off course, dosen't want to change it.

My problem is with the WSDL of the  older Web Service.

If you see the WSDL, the method "TestMethod" doesn't have a TestMethodRequest element. It have a "TestMethod" element (without the Request part).

It is posible to do that? How can I do?

How can I change the XSD to name the Request element "TestMethod" instead of "TestMethodRequest "?(and keep the Web Services working)

Thanks and sorry for my poor english